# Formula field Not working as expected

Tags: formula, relationships, checkbox

I have Formula field called "Active" with output type as Checkbox on Contracts object.

There is checkbox field on Account object and the field name "Credit Hold". This credit hold field is used to control the contract i.e, when a credit hold is checked (set to TRUE) on an account, all its related Contract records should turn inactive. Even though the End date of the contract is greater than today, we still want to make the contract inactive (we are changing the end date though).

So I setup a formula on the "Active" Field in such a way that if someone checks the credit hold checkbox on an account record, all its related Contracts will turn inactive.

In the same way, When i un-check the credit hold checkbox on the account record it should turn all the inactive contracts to active if the end date is greated than today. This part of the logic is not working with my current formula.

This is the formula i have on the Active field now:

```
IF(ISNULL(Project_Account__c), End_Date__c > TODAY(), 
End_Date__c > TODAY() && NOT(Project_Account__r.Credit_Hold__c))
```

What other condition do i have to add to make the formula work in both ways?

Comment: Can you please clarify what behavior you observe?

Comment: You run process builder on account level and can update related contract records.Any specific use case with formula field

Comment: @AdrianLarson So when i un-check the credit hold field on an account record and saved it, it saved properly. After that when i open its related inactive contract, i still see it as in-active.

Comment: So you want when Active field is true in parent account all its child accounts should be false like unchecked what about  End date of the contract date is less than today @Avinashbabu

Comment: @Pavantej  Active field on contract is a formula field from the beginning. The initial logic behind the active field is: it looks for the end date and if it is greater than or equal to today then the contract is active. if not, the contract is in-active. I modified the underlying formula to make it work for the new requirement.  what i want to know here is can we update a formula field using process builder? If so then i can build a process easily.

Comment: @Pavantej I don't understand what you meant by Child accounts. But i can explain you my use case. I have account  and that account have 5 contracts under it. Out of them 2 are in active and 3 are active. now when i check the credit hold field on account, all the active Contracts should turn in-active and when i un-check the credit hold on account, i want all inactive contracts whose end date is greater than or equal to TODAY to turn active. any contracts whose end date has already passed should remain in-active

Comment: try **(End_Date__c > TODAY())** && NOT(Project_Account__r.Credit_Hold__c) for your false condition value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding about your requirement like if active field in account is checked related contract field needs to uncheck if contract end date >today.

Change your formula like

```
IF( NOT(AND(Account.Parentaccountfield = true,Datefield>=TODAY())), true, false)
```

Please modify as per your fields and let me know if it works for you or not

Comment: You can always replace `IF(condition, false, true)` with simply `NOT(condition)`.

Comment: And you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)`, with `condition`. You should never have `IF(condition, bool, bool)` of any sort.